# HTTPError: Bad Request for Python urllib

Tags: python, urllib

This is my first project using API/python. Basically, I want to get information from trackhive.com to see where is the package. But first, to understand how it works, I'm just trying to create a track.

On the website, they give me this example:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

values = """
  {
    "tracking_number": "9361289676090919095393",
    "slug": "usps"
  }
"""

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer Token'
}
request = Request('https://private-anon-6175dd5596-trackhive.apiary-proxy.com/trackings
', data=values, headers=headers)

response_body = urlopen(request).read()
```

As I'm using Python 3, my code is

```
import json
import urllib.request

values = """
  {
    "tracking_number": "9361289676090919095393",
    "slug": "usps"
  }
"""

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer mytokenAPI'
}

url = 'https://private-anon-6175dd5596-trackhive.apiary-proxy.com/trackings'
request = urllib.request.Request(url,data=values, headers=headers)

response_body = urllib.request.urlopen(request, data=bytes(json.dumps(headers), encoding="utf-8")).read()
```

But when it calls the "urllib.request.urlopen", it returns "HTTPError: Bad Request". What am I doing wrong?

On the website, they said that the endpoint is located at: https://api.trackinghive.com. In their code, they are accessing: 'https://private-anon-6175dd5596-trackhive.apiary-proxy.com/trackings'. If I haven't access to their example, how could I know that I suppose to access this URL, and not something like "https://api.trackinghive.com/trackings"? Isn't it suppose to use the endpoint somewhere?

(I'm sorry about all these questions, I'm a little confused about how these codes with API and URL works)

I appreciate any help ^^

Edit:

Link to documentation:
https://trackhive.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/api-requirements/end-point

Comment: you could add link to documentation.

Comment: if documentation says `https://api.trackinghive.com.` then you should use it. Maybe it will redirect to some proxy url when it will need it. OR maybe they use this proxy url only in examples to show it on fake data.

Comment: I think you should keep `Bearer` in `'Authorization': 'Bearer <your token>'`, not `'Authorization': API gave by website` because `Bearer Token` is one of type of authorizations, and it may need words `Bearer` to recognize type. See [Bearer Token](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#bearer-token) in documentation for tool `Postman` which you could use to test API.

Comment: @furas I have added the link to the documentation. I will test your tips ^^

Comment: Using 
'Authorization': 'Bearer your token', remains with the same error

This is the structure that is given in the documentation:
Authorization: Bearer developer token

So it makes sense, but the Bad Request Error remains

Comment: documentation shows that it has to be `POST` request but you send it as `GET` request. It would be simpler with module `requests` instead of `urllib.request`

Comment: when I run code then I don't get `BAD Request` but `HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`. With `requests` it shows me also `'{"meta":{"code":401,"message":["Token provided is invalid."]}}'` - so all problem is to use correct Token. And it needs to register to generate Token.

Answer (score 0):

If I register on https://my.trackinghive.com/login and generate `API key` then code works for me.

---

I use `requests` instead of `urllib` because it is easier to create `POST` request. And documentation shows that it has to be `POST`, not `GET`.

And it is easier to send `JSON` data. It doesn't need header `Content-Type': 'application/json'` because `requests` will add it automatically when is use `json=...`. And it doesn't need to convert `values` to one string because `requests` will do it automatically.

BTW: I don't need module `json` to work with data. I use it only to convert it to string with indentation to display it.

```
import requests
    
values = {
   "tracking_number": "9361289676090919095393",
   "slug": "usps"
}

token = 'eyJh....'

headers = {
  'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'  # both works for me
  #'Authorization': f'{token}'
}

url = 'https://api.trackinghive.com/trackings'

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=values)

print('\n--- as text ---\n')
print(r.text)
print()

print('\n--- as dict/list ---\n')

data = r.json()
print('keys:', list(data.keys()))

print('message:', data["meta"]["message"][0])

# - show it more readable -

print('\n--- more readable ---\n')

import json

text = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
print(text)
```

Result:

```
--- as text ---

{"meta":{"code":409,"message":["Tracking already exists."]},"data":{"_id":"60a5b5a0aa4e400011a0c657","current_status":"Pending","return_to_sender":false}}


--- as dict/list ---

keys: ['meta', 'data']
messge: Tracking already exists.

--- more readable ---

{
  "meta": {
    "code": 409,
    "message": [
      "Tracking already exists."
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    "_id": "60a5b5a0aa4e400011a0c657",
    "current_status": "Pending",
    "return_to_sender": false
  }
}
```